# Neo4J Nodes not appearing

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am starting out with Neo4J and have "successfully" created the following nodes:

```
create (n1:Place{guid1:'8a5d6560a50f49a2a9dad20ad9165d3f',Value:'029/03',guid2:'8a5d6560a50f49a2a9dad20ad9165d3f'})
create (n2:PhysicalAsset{guid1:'0718568c0f8148409d736b8696f8f689',Name:'029/03-01',guid2:'0718568c0f8148409d736b8696f8f689'})
create (n3:PhysicalAsset{guid1:'32b1c26893a34fdba7b2ae571ead9a5e',Name:'029/03-J5',guid2:'32b1c26893a34fdba7b2ae571ead9a5e'})
create (n4:PhysicalAsset{guid1:'c76a6bf5e9834f5cbb0797a3fb24ab8d',Name:'029/03-P3',guid2:'c76a6bf5e9834f5cbb0797a3fb24ab8d'})
create (n5:PhysicalAsset{guid1:'f9481b416bed47feb11e454b367c75f5',Name:'029/03-TP6',guid2:'f9481b416bed47feb11e454b367c75f5'})
create (n6:PhysicalAsset{guid1:'f9371eef82fa4c68a4a2d76e7f3cadd8',Name:'029/03-TR4',guid2:'f9371eef82fa4c68a4a2d76e7f3cadd8'})
create (n7:Place{guid1:'1780459a04b04d91930cc9e6380033a5',Name:'029/03a',guid2:'1780459a04b04d91930cc9e6380033a5'})
create (n8:PhysicalAsset{guid1:'ea1264e2e5c24870bdb5b6ad06fad7a4',Name:'029/03a-02',guid2:'ea1264e2e5c24870bdb5b6ad06fad7a4'})
create (n9:PhysicalAsset{guid1:'97b9e8b93ded4b03a66f15c81243ceb3',Name:'029/03a-03',guid2:'97b9e8b93ded4b03a66f15c81243ceb3'})
create (n10:PhysicalAsset{guid1:'cda34fc06044466fb4b9d9340fbee999',Name:'029/03a-05',guid2:'cda34fc06044466fb4b9d9340fbee999'})
```

Successfully because I get a notification that they have been created, but when I try to view them, I get "Displaying 0 Nodes 0 Relationships.

Why?

Comment: How are you trying to view them (i.e. what is the Cypher query)?

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you're trying to view these nodes, including any usage of the web portal and cypher queries. As of right now, it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: There are also labels and rel-type overviews in the left sidebar on top (3 bubbles) that you can click to see a sample of nodes with that label.

Comment: Thanks William, David and Michael...the only problem I really had was between my ear buds. All good now.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to show everything

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n;
```

It's better to use labels

```
MATCH (place:Place), (pa:PhysicalAsset)
RETURN place, pa
```